# angularjs ajax with PHP variable

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json, angularjs

I have a code in angularjs which loops an ajax json response like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="post in posts">
{{post.title}}
{{post.url}}
</div>
```

It works fine. How do I do to pass a PHP variable based on the json?

**Lets say the json looks have a structure this:**

```
post
    my_slug
    my_title
post
    my_slug2
    my_title2
```

**I have a PHP array like this:**

```
my_slug
    url
my_slug2
    url2
```

**my_slug** in PHP matches **my_slug** in json.

**Ajax call**

```
var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);
app.controller("PostsCtrl", function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('<?php echo u(); ?>test/json.txt').
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.posts = data;
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    });
});
```

**The result should look somethins like this:**

```
<div>
    my_title
    url
</div>
<div>
    my_title2
    url2
</div>
```

In the angularjs json loop I want to get `url` and `url2` from my PHP array. How? Can I pass the PHP array with my Ajax response?

Comment: You question is not clear! Make it more concrete.

Comment: I also added a "result" of how it could look like when looping from ajax json and PHP array.

Comment: You lost me here Jens, if you use $http.get to call PHP script and it does return a well formatted JSON then it is straight forward how to use it in ng-repeat. Please explain further what is it that you want to achieve

Comment: Show how the actual variables really look like, from your indentation it's not clear if it's a key or value.

Answer (score 0):

assign your php data to a variable then loop through the data to manipulate it before you assign it.

```
 $scope.postsPhp = [{$postsJSON}]; /// I usually make the php arrays json

 success(function(data, status, headers, config) { for (var i = 0; i <
 data.length; i++) { 
   data[i].title = data[i].url + ' ' + $scope.postsPhp[i].url; }
```

$scope.posts = data;
 });

Comment: he doesn't have to join those two strings to display them, he already have {{post.url}} in the html